# Confusion regarding second quantised notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, notation, second-quantization

Suppose Hamiltonian of the system in 2nd quantised notation is
$H= t\sum_{x=1}^{N}d_{x}^{\dagger}d_{x}$.

Does this mean that eigenstates of the Hamiltonian is $N$-fold degenerate with energy $t$?

Comment: Could you clarify if $d$ is bosonic or fermionic? That is, which of $[d^\dagger,d]=1$ or $\{d^\dagger,d\}=1$ holds?

Comment: 'd' is a fermionic operator.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed, there are $N$ identical states, each having energy $t$.

**Remark:**
Note that usually $t$ is used for a hopping integral, as in
$$
H= \epsilon_0\sum_{x=1}^Nd_x^\dagger d_x + t\sum_{x=1}^N\left(d_x^\dagger d_{x+1} + h.c.\right)
$$

**Remark**
In view of the comments and the other answer, it is necessary to note that what we mean here depends on the context. Specifically:

- one may speak about a single-particle Hamiltonian in second quantized notation (or simply the fact that the system is composed of $N$ identical orbitals), which si how I understood the OP
- one may also speak about many-body states, as suggested by the use of the second quantization.

Note however that second quantization is widely used to deal with one-particle problems, so one cannot reasonably claim that only one interpretation is correct.

Comment: This is misleading. Assuming $d$ to be fermionic in OP's post there are $2^N$ states. The phrase 'identical states' doesn't have any particular meaning. Of these $2^N$ states, there are $N$ different energy levels which have degeneracies $\binom{N}{r}$, thus only the first excited energy level is $N$ fold degenerate.

Comment: @jacob1729 I see what you mean. It depends on how one interprets the question.

Comment: I don't know of any interpretation of 'degeneracy' that would be correct to say it is $N$-fold unless you very specifically restrict to only states on energies $0,t$.

Comment: @jacob1729 Perhaps you are used to this form of the Hamiltonian in a specific context. It could be just a one-particle Hamiltonian in second-quantized notation - not uncommon when studying, e.g., scattering problems in solid state.

Comment: @jacob1729 I added a remark to reflect your comment.

Comment: I think the above Hamiltonian "H" gives single particle eigenstates , which have same energy "t". The number of such eigenstates is "N".  From this we can construct multiparticle states, by filling various states with a  fermionic particle. There will be degeneracy in these multi-particle states as well.

Comment: (cont..) When we consider  many particle ground state , many particle- 1st excited state ,2nd excited state, etc ,it will consists of different particle in each excited state. But how can be definition of excited state be meaningful when particles number changes. I think in condensed matter , people view energy spectrum in terms of only single particle states. Any comments on this will be usefull.

Comment: In a closed system the excitations occur only between the states with the same number of particles, but in an open one the particles can flow back and fourth. On a more formal side: Fock space in second quantization includes states with all posisble numbers of particles. Also, excitations are not the only interesting aspect in condensed matter. Phase transitions may be affected by the number of particles - the Hamiltonian in question is a building block of the Hubbard model, where the *filling factor* (i.e., the number of particles per site) is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

The degeneracy of the state with energy $nt$ is the number of ways you can make the integer $n$ out of $N$ numbers eg if $N=3$ and then we can get $4t$ as
$$
4+0+0\\
0+4+0\\
\vdots
$$
etc, and
$$
3+1+1\\
1+3+1\\
\vdots
$$
or
$$
2+0+2\\
0+2+2\\
\vdots
$$
I leave it to you to compute the degeracy of the level $E=nt$!

Comment: Remark that this answer assumes the system is a collection of harmonic oscillators (ie bosons). The notation in the OP is ambiguous but I would tend towards assuming it means fermions, in which case obviously $4t$ isn't allowed by Pauli.

Comment: (But this is a fairly simple change that the OP should be able to adapt to their case. The fermion combinatorics are simply a bit easier.)